# How to open a link in webpart on the same page.

Tags: web-part

I have a graphic which hold some links to a document library. 
What I like to do is that all content which is display through the link opens below the graphic.
Not load a new page or tab.

I don’t know if it’s possible with a page view webpart

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You should edit the page and add those document library views. Then hide all of them by default.

Handle the click event of the Graphic using JavaScript. Then Show/Hide the library webpart using JavaScript.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. Do you have a script example?